# Generating a list of random numbers that follows a pattern

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, random

I'm a beginner to Mathematica. I'm writing a code to design a 4-bar linkage mechanism that traces a path in 2D space. I got the modelling done right, now I'm writing my own implementation of a [genetic algorithm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Genetic_algorithm) to solve the optimization problem.

So in creating the population that will be passed later to the fitness evaluation function, things will be much easier if the randomly generated numbers follow the certain pattern that will make one of the linkages rotate fully.

Currently here is my function to generate the population:

```
popCreate[maxValue_, cromosomeSize_, popSize_] :=
  (* Create the initial population *)
  Module[{m = maxValue, c = cromosomeSize, s = popSize}, 
    RandomSeed[0];
    (* Create random numbers with table over the size and 
       table over the population size *)
    Table[Table[RandomReal[{0, m}], c], s]]
```

I've come across this code from another question here:

```
RandomReal[1, {100, 2}] /. {x_, y_} /; y > x :> {y, x}
```

Quite honestly I don't know how to adapt this to my needs.
Here is my needed pattern:

```
L + S ≤ P + Q
```

where

$\qquad$`L` is the  biggest number (longest link)
$\qquad$`S` is the smallest number (shortest link)
$\qquad$`P` and `Q` are the other two links

My question is:

- How do I create a function that returns a list of randomly generated numbers that are normally distributed and that follow this specific pattern only?

I was thinking of using `If` to clean up the unusable arrays that function will generate, yet I'm sure there must be an elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Your could not have tested your `popCreate` function, because if you had, you would know that it doesn't work -- it returns `Null` rather than a population of chromosomes. Try the much simpler, `popCreate[maxValue_, cromosomeSize_, popSize_] := (RandomSeed[0];   Table[Table[RandomReal[{0, maxValue}], cromosomeSize], popSize])`, which actually returns an array of random Reals.

Comment: Actually, I've been using this function for a while. I added the ; at the end because I was testing the other code this 'RandomReal[1, {100, 2}] /. {x_, y_} /; y > x :> {y, x}' Let me edit the question. My current version runs and returns the array

Comment: Do you really want to sample linkage values from a normal distribution rather than a uniform distribution? If so, you must supply the mean and standard deviation to used to `popCreate` and use the functions `RandomVariate` and `NormalDistribution`, not `RandomReal`.

Comment: okay sounds like a good point... I'm taking this step by step, though. Right now I'm trying to get the population to be more suitable by following the pattern I mentioned.

Comment: Something along the lines of `Cases[Sort /@ RandomReal[{0, 10}, {100, 4}], {s_, p_, q_, l_} /; l + s <= p + q]`? Note that these come from a *uniform* distribution, not a normal one. For that you need `RandomVariate` and `NormalDistribution` as @m_goldberg mentioned.

Comment: `popCreate` is still a silly, over-complicated implementation of a very simple function.

Comment: @MarcoB That one works perfectly... Can you help me understand the syntax? You're Sorting the randomly generated numbers, then matching the pattern? Hence s_ comes first and l_ comes last?

Comment: The reason for my criticism of your question is that the bad code and discussions of genetic algorithms and of sampling distributions make your real problem unclear, almost invisible. We like questions to be better focused on the main issue than this one is.

Comment: @m_goldberg My apologies if my question is unclear. I tried to give some background so it makes more sense. Would it have been better if I just asked about the desired outcome question without any other details?

Comment: The question seems clear enough to me in its present form. +1 for your efforts.

Comment: @MahmoudRagab That's correct: generate *n* 4-tuples of random numbers, sort each one of them so the length of the "shortest" linkage corresponds to the first number, the longest is the last, then select only those lists whose members obey your constraint.

Comment: @MarcoB Crystal clear... Many thanks for the help...

Comment: @MacroB I'm just curious; this way I don't have control over how many 4-tuples I get (My population in this case). Is there a way I can force Mathematica to generate 100 4-tuples matching my constraint?

Comment: Mahmoud, you can do *rejection sampling* and modify @Marco's suggestion: generate those numbers within a `While[]` loop and keep on going until you get 100 of these tuples, perhaps using `Sow[]`/`Reap[]` to store them.

Comment: @J.M. Got It! Thanks J.M

Comment: @MarcoB Hi, just to follow up... hmmm I know this sounds weird but the function sometimes generates tuples that don't match the pattern. like these:  `{12.4277, 8.05452, 13.396, 20.9104, 68.4237, 57.2897}, {29.7354, 11.3674, 25.499, 28.9404, 59.296, 59.6355}, {4.81485, 2.78418, -0.0973677, 42.4423, 51.5949, 52.2937}`Here is my implementation:`Cases[Sort /@ RandomReal[{0, 60}, {200, 6}], {t_, y_, s_, p_, q_, l_} /; l + s < p + q]` Any explanation?